# how to insert <a> in <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating `<td>` and adding data to it.

```
$("<td>").addClass("tableCell1").text(mydata).appendTo(trow);
```

now if I have to create an `<a>` tag inside  how to do it?
example:

```
<td headers="xx">
                  <a href="#" title="zz</a>
                </td>
```

EDIT:

```
$("<td>").addClass("tableCell1").text(mydata).appendTo(trow);
```

is working fine but

```
$('a').attr({ href: '#', title: 'title here' }).appendTo($('td')).appendTo(trow);
```

is not working, I am not getting the `<a>` under `<td>`

Comment: Regarding your edit, it doesn't work because you're not creating any elements, only selecting them. I added an answer below that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you're trying to create the `<a>` and the `<td>` at the same time. If you're trying to add the `<a>` at a different event, you would need a different solution.

```
$("<td/>",{"class":"tableCell1", text:mydata})
    .append($("<a/>",{ href:"#", title:"zz"}))
    .appendTo(trow);
```

Note that you didn't indicate any content for the `<a>` in your question. If not styled properly, it will be invisible. If you want to add some text, add `text: "some text"` to the `<a>` creation.

Comment: @Sarfraz - You deleted your answer, but if you're watching, you need to pass an entire tag in order to *create* an element. `$('a')` selects, `$('<a>')` creates.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
$("td.tableCell1").append('<a href="#" title="zz"></a>');
```

**EDIT:** Or for even more safety in selecting the proper `<td>`, you should be able to use

```
$("td.tableCell1", trow).append('<a href="#" title="zz"></a>');
```

For even EVEN more safety, you could

```
$("td.tableCell1:lastChild", trow).append('<a href="#" title="zz"></a>');
```